# R: How to intersect two genomic ranges

Tags: r, intervals

I've two DF with genomic coordinates (let's say DF A and B). I want to intersect A and B. Each A entry possesses multiple B entries. What I want is to output for each entry in A the max of a specific column in B that overlaps with A. I tried to use subsetByOverlaps but it's not really what I want. For example :

```
A
chr start   end
chr1    10  100 
chr2    5   200 

B
chr start   end value
chr1    20  30  5
chr1    30  45  10
chr1    40  50  2
chr1    50  80  7
chr2    10  20  5
chr2    100 110 8
chr2    150 170 3
```

Gives me

```
 chr start  end value
chr1    10  100    10
chr2     5  200     8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way with expanding the A data frame to the length of B and comparing row by row finding the `max` of each group:

```
A2 <- unique(A)[match(B$chr, A$chr),]
ind <- B$start >= A2$start & B$end <= A2$end
A$value <- tapply(B$value[ind], B$chr[ind], FUN=max)
A
#   chr start end value
#1 chr1    10 100    10
#2 chr2     5 200     8
```

Comment: It didn't work. I think it's because A entry are always included in B entries (A entries are very small intervals ~ 10nt - and B entries are very large ones ~100K to Mb). Sorry I forgot to tell you that. I think I will try to adapt your code in order to make it work ;) thanks